# Uso de "Contains" em expressão de busca

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

Tenho uma *string* `_Users` do tipo `List`, nela contém várias linhas.

Cada linha é composta por um inteiro e uma *string* separados por virgula (no geral é apenas uma *string*): ID (apenas números),nome (letras e números).

O que estou tentando fazer é encontrar em qual linha o ID está localizado.

Se eu quero encontrar o *index* do ID 1, a função `Contains()` irá me retornar a primeira linha que contiver "1", isso irá atrapalhar se existir um usuário com nome, por exemplo: "joao123".

```
int i = _Users.FindIndex(a => a.Contains(UserID.ToString()));

var dados = _Users[i];

string[] dado = dados.Split(',');
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta, você precisa capturar exatamente o usuário com o "`id`" igual a **`UserID`**.

Desta forma você não precisa de comparação usando `Contains`, é possível quebrar a string do usuário pela vírgula usando o método `Split()`.

```
var userId = 1;
var users = new [] { "1,Joao", "2,Marcos", "3,Joaquim123", "31,Jonas" };

// Faça assim para obter o usuário com exatamente o "id" = userId
var usuario = users.First(u => u.Split(',')[0] == userId.ToString());

// Faça isso para obter OS USUÁRIOS onde o "id" CONTENHA userId
var usuarios = users.Where(u => u.Split(',')[0].Contains(userId.ToString()));

Console.WriteLine($"Usuário com Id = {userId}");
Console.WriteLine($"\t{usuario}");

Console.WriteLine($"\n\nUsuário onde o Id contém {userId}");
foreach(var u in usuarios)
    Console.WriteLine($"\t{u}");
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gnCNQW)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ. Não sei se quer pegar o `id` ou o `nome`, fiz ambos:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var lista = new List<string> { "1,Joao",
            "2,Maria",
            "3,José1" };
        var nome = lista.Select(x => x.Split(',')).SingleOrDefault(a => a[1].Contains("1"));
        var id = lista.Select(x => x.Split(',')).SingleOrDefault(a => a[0].Contains("1"));
        WriteLine(nome[1]);
        WriteLine(id[1]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0junTf). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rfwWqm). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/SplitString.cs).

Você precisa primeiro isolar o que está dando ruído, então o `Split()` tem que ocorrer antes, e a pesquisa deve ocorrer só no nome, aí ele te devolve o item já *splitado*.

Answer (score 0):

Seria mais fácil se você apenas escrevesse uma dessas linhas como exemplo.

Se ela se parece com `1, Funaldo de Tal`, você poderia usar `StartsWith` ao invés de `Contains`, dessa forma se o ID não for encontrado logo no início, a comparação retornará `false`.

`int i = _Users.FindIndex(a => a.StartsWith(UserID.ToString()));`

Comment: Nessa sua solução com `StartsWith(UserID)` tem um furo, porque, se `UserID == 1`, por exemplo, a sua solução poderia retornar um `UserID == 10`, se a lista não estiver ordenada.